# How to get the total playtime for specific steam app?

Tags: api, steam

So far I read the documentation at https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats#GetGlobalStatsForGame and I got this:

```
GET https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalStatsForGame/v1/?appid=779340&count=1&name[0]=TOTAL_PLAY_TIME&startdate=1567301084&enddate=1567381084
```

However, it returns

```
{"response":{"result":8,"error":"Stat 'TOTAL_PLAY_TIME' is not an aggregated stat"}}
```

How can I get the total playtime for any specific game/app on steam?

It should be possible, since sites like https://steamspy.com are able to display stats like the average playtime.

Comment: Are your privacy settings for your profile & games set to public? If not, they may need to be for this to function.

Comment: They are set to public. I can get my total playtime for a specific app, but not total playtime of all steam users for a specific app.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry -- I thought this was for a single account, not multiple. As someone else said it's likely not possible because not all users have a public profile and also GDPR limitations.

Comment: did you ever find a way to get hours played ?

Comment: I ended up using https://steamspy.com. I'll add an answer to my own question then, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out if it is possible by only relying on the steam api.
However for my use case it was sufficient to use the data https://steamspy.com provides. (Thanks @Fliere)
Specifically I used the `average_forever` values, which can be queried via https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=appdetails&appid=779340.
`appid` being the steam appid of the game you want to get the data on.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I don't see a way of using the API. That API retrieves the global stats **PERCENTAGES** for the specified app.

I believe steamspy uses average playtimes. They collect such info because of users login into their site and 'depositing' their information and playtimes. If they have enough players who sign into their site they can calculate the total playtime by guessing the amount of people who own the game multiplied by the average playtime.